# Remove a list of user-defined class object and combine value of one property in Java

Tags: java

I have a `Employee` class

```
class Employee {

    private final String id;
    private float compensation;

    public Employee(String id, float compensation) {
        this.id = id;
        this.compensation = compensation;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public float getCompensation() {
        return compensation;
    }
}
```

Then I have a list of Employees

```
List<Employee> payment = Arrays.asList(
      new Employee("1", 3000.00),
      new Employee("1", 6000.00),
      new Employee("2", 5000.00),
      new Employee("3", 4000.00),
);
```

How to dedup the list by the employee ID and combine the compensation?

Expected result:

```
List<Employee> newPayment = Arrays.asList(
      new Employee("1", 9000.00),
      new Employee("2", 5000.00),
      new Employee("3", 4000.00),
);
```

Comment: One approach to remove duplicates from the list of Employees based on their ID and aggregate their compensation is to utilize a HashMap to maintain a record of each unique employee's compensation. By using the HashMap, it becomes easier to track the compensation of each Employee by their ID and combine the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Java 8 streams and collectors to group the employees by their `id` and then sum their compensations. Here's an example code snippet:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


class Dedup {
    public static List<Employee> dedupByIds(List<Employee> payment) {
        return payment.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getId, Collectors.summingDouble(Employee::getCompensation)))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> new Employee(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().floatValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

and then call this function by the list that you want to dedup.

```
List<Employee> payment = Arrays.asList(
                new Employee("1", 3000.00f),
                new Employee("1", 6000.00f),
                new Employee("2", 5000.00f),
                new Employee("3", 4000.00f)
                );

List<Employee> newPayment = Dedup.dedupByIds(payment);

//printing values to console 
for (Employee e : newPayment) {
    System.out.println(e.getId() + " : " + e.getCompensation());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To dedup the list by employee ID and combine the compensation, you can use Java streams and grouping operations. Here's an example:

```java
List<Employee> newPayment = payment.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getId,
                 Collectors.summingDouble(Employee::getCompensation)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new Employee(entry.getKey(), (float) entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this code, we first use the `groupingBy()` collector to group the Employee objects by their id property. We also use the `summingDouble()` collector to calculate the sum of compensation for each group.

This creates a `Map<String, Double>` where the keys are the employee IDs and the values are the total compensations for each group.

Next, we convert the map entries back to Employee objects using the `map()` method, and finally collect them into a new list using the `toList()` collector. The result is a new list of Employee objects with the combined compensations.